# Displaying Text (Tags) That Was Selected In Another View

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

`**Background**
I am creating an app where the user can create quotes and a part of that creating the quote process is that they can select a tag to fit that quotes them so if it's a happy quote the user can select a happy tag. I'm also very new to SwiftUI so please understand if my code isn't the best, and if it wasn't explained the best, but feel completely free to ask me more questions and if I need to provide my entire Xcode project for better understanding - PLEASE TELL :)

**Tag UI**
I am using a package that essentially styles text that you provide it into looking like a tag - it also lets the user select the tag (which is important to my problem). The tag implementation is this code from GitHub - https://github.com/HappyIosDeveloper/SwiftUI-TagView .

**Set-Up**
I have 2 views (I have more, but I believe they aren't important to the problem) - AddQuoteView and TagSelectionView.
On the AddQuoteView the user can create a quote with an quote (text), author, etc. they also have the ability to select a tag to fit the quote, when they click on the plus button to add a tag they are presented the TagSelectionView (presented as a view in a Half Sheet - thanks to this SwiftUI package - https://github.com/franklynw/HalfASheet .
On the TagSelectionView the user can select up to 3 tags (selecting and unselecting them as they please). (This TagSelectionView is supported by a TagView that styles, creates the ability to select them, etc.) Once the user is happy with their tag choices, they can press a button on the TagSelectionView that dismisses/exits them out of that view and back to the AddQuoteView.
I also have it set up to a Firebase that stores the quotes the user creates.

**Problem**
I want the user to be shown the tags they selected in the TagSelectionView on the AddQuoteView, but they won't be displayed.

**Code displayed below is the code I deemed to be fairly important for this problem**

```
**AddQuoteView code:**

@State private var tagsIsSelected = true
@State private var showingTagSelectionView = false

VStack{
HStack{
        Image(systemName: "tag.fill")
            .scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1)
        Text("Label")

        Spacer()
                                Button {
            showingTagSelectionView.toggle()
        } label: {
                                    HStack{
                Image(systemName: "plus")

                if tagsIsSelected == false {
                    Text("Add Tag")
                        .bold()
                }
            }
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .frame(height: 36)
                .cornerRadius(18)
                .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1))
        }
                                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())


    }
}
HalfASheet(isPresented: $showingTagSelectionView, title: "Tags (3 per quote)") {
    TagSelectionView()
}
            .height(.proportional(0.58))


    **TagSelectionView code**

        ScrollView{
    TagView(tags: [
        TagViewItem(title: " Acceptance", isSelected: false), TagViewItem(title: " Adventure", isSelected: false)
        //More tags (but just not shown here)
    ])
}
        .offset(x: 0, y: 40)
    }


**TagView code - styles and creates abilities for the tags**

import SwiftUI

struct TagViewItem: Hashable {
    var title: String
    var isSelected: Bool
    
    static func == (lhs: TagViewItem, rhs: TagViewItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.isSelected == rhs.isSelected
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(title)
        hasher.combine(isSelected)
    }
}

struct TagView: View {
    @State var tags: [TagViewItem]
    @State private var totalHeight = CGFloat.zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                self.generateContent(in: geometry)
}
        }
        .frame(height: totalHeight)
    }

    private func generateContent(in g: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
    var width = CGFloat.zero
    var height = CGFloat.zero
    var selectedTagCount = tags.filter { $0.isSelected }.count // Track the number of selected tags
    return ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
        ForEach(tags.indices) {
            index in
                item(for: tags[index].title, isSelected: tags[index].isSelected)
                    .padding([.horizontal, .vertical], 4)
                .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: {
                    d in
                        if(abs(width - d.width) > g.size.width) {
                width = 0
                height -= d.height
            }
            let result = width
            if tags[index].title == self.tags.last!.title {
                width = 0
            } else {
                width -= d.width
            }
            return result
        })
                    .alignmentGuide(.top, computeValue: {
            d in
                        let result = height
                        if tags[index].title == self.tags.last!.title {
            height = 0
        }
                        return result
    })
                    .onTapGesture {
        if selectedTagCount < 3 || tags[index].isSelected == true {
            tags[index].isSelected.toggle()
            selectedTagCount += tags[index].isSelected ? 1 : -1
        }
    }
}
        }.background(viewHeightReader($totalHeight))
    }

    private func item(for text: String, isSelected: Bool) -> some View {
    Text(text)
        .bold()
        .foregroundColor(isSelected ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1340637264, green: 0.6421895015, blue: 0.7360979563, alpha: 1)) : Color.white)
        .padding()
        .lineLimit(1)
        .background(isSelected ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.301058143, blue: 0.5746451229, alpha: 1)) : Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2903293967, green: 0.2863105237, blue: 0.2821627259, alpha: 1)))
        .frame(height: 36)
        .cornerRadius(18)
}

    private func viewHeightReader(_ binding: Binding < CGFloat >) -> some View {
    return GeometryReader {
        geometry -> Color in
            let rect = geometry.frame(in: .local)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            binding.wrappedValue = rect.size.height
        }
        return .clear
    }
}
}
```

I've tried simply putting the tags the user selected into an array and then generating that array into the AddQuoteView with a ForEach, but they still weren't displayed.

Comment: from your problem description, looks like you want to pass the selected tags from one view to another. So
have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)  and ways to pass data from one view to another. If you are targeting ios17, see [Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)